# Local variable always nil when trying to render partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, view, partial

I'm getting a really strange issue with a partial when trying to render a collection, I've even tried different approaches.

Here is my partial code (for debugging):

```
<pre><%= item.inspect -%></pre>
```

And here are my attempts to use it:

```
<%= render 'item', :collection => @foo.items %>
<%= render 'item', :collection => @foo.items, :as => :item %>

<% @foo.items.each do |item| %>
    <%= render 'item', :locals => {:item => item} %>
    <%= render 'item', :object => item %>
<% end %>
```

In each of those scenarios the partial just outputs nil, however if I pop a `item.inspect` inside my each loop the object details are displayed as expected.

The only thing I thought that could be a problem is that the `items` association is a short name mapped to a different class, so I thought that Rails 3 automagic thing might be assigning it to a variable to match that class name, however if I try and output that I get the 'undefined local variable error'.

I hope I'm overlooking something silly.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Have you tried this already? —

```
<% @foo.items.each do |item| %>
    <%= render 'item', :item => item %>
<% end %>
```

**Update**

Here's a guess for the collection:

```
<%= render :partial => 'item', :collection => @foo.items, :as => :item  %>
```

Comment: I was pretty sure I had among all those variations I tried but I guess not as it seems to work. Still seems strange (and annoying) that I can't get collection to work though.

Comment: Well, good thing if it works. I've added something I'd still try concerning the collection.

Comment: Wow if you don't include the :partial => 'item' part and use the new Rails 3 shorthand of just the partial name it doesn't work, but being specific makes it work.