# Rails 3 Render Partial nil object

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, partial-views

I feel like I'm doing something dumb here. I'm making a simple TODO list app (I realize there are already a million of them). I have a project definition and the various statuses that a task within in that project can be assigned.

No matter what, I'm receiving the following error message when hitting the page:

> undefined method `title' for nil:NilClass

[This question about nil objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4714926/local-variable-always-nil-when-trying-to-render-partial) is extremely similar, however, the suggested solutions don't seem to fix the issue I'm encountering. I only have one status associated with the project and it is not nil. I'm wondering if this issue has anything to do with the statuses being an association...

In my project I have:

```
    <% @project.statuses.each do |s| %> 
      <%= s.inspect %> 
      <%= render 'statuses/show', :status => s %>
   <% end %>

#if I take out the render line - the status shows up
```

The status right now is basically just a generic scaffolded view -- if I was passing the data from a controller directly it would receive an object @status.
...
I have tried this with `render :partial..., :locals => { :status = s}` etc. etc. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

**Update - Added _show Partial:**

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<p>
  <b>Title:</b>
  <%= @status.title %>
</p>

<p>
  <b>Description:</b>
  <%= @status.description %>
</p>

<p>
  <b>Active:</b>
  <%= @status.active %>
</p>

<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_status_path(@status) %> |
<%= link_to 'Back', statuses_path %>
```

**Update - Added more of the error message**

```
NoMethodError in Projects#show

Showing /home/.../app/views/statuses/_show.html.erb where line #5 raised:

undefined method `title' for nil:NilClass
```

Comment: Could you show us the content of statuses/_show partial?

Comment: Plus perhaps the part of the stack trace that points to the culprit line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the problem is that you're referring to `@status` in the ERB partial, where as  you should be referring to `status`, without the leading `@`.

The `@status` means to look for a defined *instance variable*. While passing in the `:status => s` means that the view will have access to `s` via a *local variable* named `status`.

Also, if simply `:status => s` does not work, try `:locals => {:status => s}`. In any case, access `status` in the view, not `@status`.

Comment: Thank you that's exactly what it was.

Answer (score 1):

The biggest problem is that `:status` is an option for render.  It renders the http code like 200 or :ok.

What should work is:

```
<%= render :partial => 'statuses/show', :locals => { :status => s } %>
```

and don't use the `@` for the variable.

```
<%= status.title %>
```